# Score in profile page shows zero, but its tooltip shows 51

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, tag-score, tooltips

In [this user's profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4019207/iu-tub?tab=profile), I see:

[image]

I hover over the "*SCORE **0**"* and I see:

[image]

Questions:

1. Why does the tooltip show 51 score, while the page shows 0 score?
2. Whatever the reason is, shouldn't it be 52 instead of 51 as one of the OP's questions has 52 score as seen in the above screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value being shown there is the answer score.  The user has asked [four questions in the c tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4019207+is%3Aquestion), and their score is around 52 for questions (with any latency in that being attributable to caching).

Contrast this with [your own profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049655/cool-guy); you've asked ~17 questions in the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag for a score of ~150, but you gave ~456 answers in the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag for a score of ~657.

Comment: I get it.. I think "_score_" should be "_answer score_" to avoid confusion.